# Hi, I have the jquery dynamic append tag error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code,

I want to resize .modal-left or .modal-right
But, function is not working.
When i executed in the browser console, it worked.

I think this problem caused by dynamic append tag.
What shoud i do?

Thanks for reading my problem.

```
 function getArtworkDetail(artwork_num){
    var modalMask = $('<div class="modalMask"></div>'); 
    var modalContent = $('<div class="modalContent"></div>');

    $.ajax({
        url : "/artwork/profile_portfolio?artwork_num="+artwork_num,
        type : 'get',
        success : function(data){
            $(modalContent).append(data);
        },error : function(e){
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
    })

    $(modalMask).append(modalContent);
    $('.modal').append(modalMask);

    $('.modalMask').css('height',$('body').height()+38);
    console.log($('.detail-left'));

    if($('.detail-left').height() > $('.detail-right').height()){
        $('.detail-right').css('height',$('.detail-left').height()+'px');
    }else{
        $('.detail-left').css('height',$('.detail-right').height()+'px');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please keep in mind that `Ajax Call` is by default `asynchronous` call ... so in your case code which is out side `success` method will execute first after that your `ajax` call get response and it will run `success` method of your `ajax` call .

So solution is that ... you have to put your code into ajax `success` method as below.

Put your code into `success` method as below.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/artwork/profile_portfolio?artwork_num="+artwork_num,
    type : 'get',
    success : function(data){
        $(modalContent).append(data);
        $(modalMask).append(modalContent);
        $('.modal').append(modalMask);

        $('.modalMask').css('height',$('body').height()+38);
        console.log($('.detail-left'));

        if($('.detail-left').height() > $('.detail-right').height()){
            $('.detail-right').css('height',$('.detail-left').height()+'px');
}
       else{
    $('.detail-left').css('height',$('.detail-right').height()+'px');
          }
        },error : function(e){
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
});
```

Comment: @suk - Glad to help you :-) ... please `accept` the answer ... it will helps other to find out correct solution ....
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows, remove extra '$'

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/artwork/profile_portfolio?artwork_num="+artwork_num,
    type : 'get',
    success : function(data){
        modalContent.append(data);
    },error : function(e){
        console.log(e.responseText);
    }
})
```

Comment: i don't try it, but i'm really appreciate for your help :)